# Plone - removing <No reference> option from ReferenceWidget

Tags: reference, widget, field, plone

When I use ReferenceField with ReferenceWidget, there are always options which refer to real objects, and one, on the top, named `<No reference>`. It is possible to hide that option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, set the `required` property of the field to True.

```
ReferenceField(
    name='references',
    required=True,
    # ...
)
```

Comment: Hmm, but i dont want to make it required. Maby is it possible to rename it? // Ah, ok. Its not that important. Thank you for answer, as always perfect.

Comment: You could use translate the `label_no_reference` message id in the `plone` domain in your product, that's usually the easiest way to rename a label like that.